# Explorer.exe Constantly Crashing at Login

Tags: windows, windows-xp, crash

I've got to admit I'm completely lost on this one. My bosses personal computer has been acting up for a while since the IT guy he was using cloned his old HD to his new HD in the same computer. Basically what was happening is his account would start taking forever at loading personal settings. Then Internet Explorer and most any other Browser would crash immediately after opening. Then I ended up working on it and did the below:

1. Malwarebytes (No threats)
2. Microsoft Security Essentials (No Threats)
3. sfc /scannow (nothing)
4. chckdsk /r /f (nothing)
5. Repair Install -> Windows Updates
6. Machine seemed to be working for about 2 weeks then explorer started crashing at login
7. Managed to create a new user and was able to login fine.
8. Disabled non-essential services and startup items and he was able to login fine

Now he can't login even with almost everything disabled. He logs in and explorer.exe crashes. I try to open it using the Task Manager->File->New Task->explorer.exe and it crashes again right away.

The events in the event viewer: 1000/1002 basically stating Explorer.exe is the faulting module and crashed. Also sometimes seeing drwtsn32.exe in the faulting application module errors.

Comment: Is it ok under another session?

Comment: looks like a re-install to me!!

Comment: What do you mean under another session? This isn't a TS, just a standard workstation.

Comment: When you log into the computer with, by example, the admin account and you have that problem, can you try with another user account? With or without admin privileges... Let me know.

Comment: Update: Ok, I noticed your update about it works for a while with another account but then it crashes. With all you tried, don't waste more time on a single workstation... Do a clean reinstall. If it would be a TS where several people logs on, I'd spend all my time trying to fix this but... not in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mucker's suggestion isn't that bad. Since it's working fine for some days with a new user account but then crash, I wouldn't spent that much time on troubleshooting the issue because obviously, there's something wrong with the process explorer.exe. I've seen that before and trying to troubleshoot a basic Windows process that is crashing regularly is a pain in the neck. I would also perform a clean reinstall if I'd be faced to this issue.

Comment: Looks like I'll probably have to do a new clean install unfortunately then I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should try rebuilding the profile so that it will work just like it does on the other user.

Comment: Just an update in regards to this. The new user I created was working fine initially. However, now it seems to crash. I can however manually run Explorer.exe and sometimes it works.

Comment: Have you tried a system restore?